# Site Crashes When Updating to WordPress (Version 3.6)

Tags: wp-admin, updates, automatic-updates, fatal-error

I was just clicking the update button behind in the admin panel. it said no enough space in my hosting. then i went and removed some files and tried again then it was processing the wp update. suddenly it took me to a blank page and now the entire site looks empty.

I am guessing this could be due to space limitation in hosting account. even though i removed a few and tried updating, it might have meet not enough space in the middle of updating and its leading to this issue.

Also in the mean time i tried accessing this page: `www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/update-core.php` and got the below error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function nocache_headers() in /home/webmas8/public_html/azraar/wp-admin/admin.php on line 32

This is the website that causes the issue: http://www.azraar.com/

Comment: mazraara, I've moved the comment in a answer, as suggested by moderators. If it works for you can check it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the update wasn't complete and some files are missing.

If you have FTP access, follow these steps.

1. Download you `wp-config.php` and save it somewhere.
2. In the wp folder on server delete everything **but** the wp-content folder
3. Have a DB backup, if you can
4. Download from wordpress.org the zip of wordpress and extract it
5. At this moment remove the `wp-content` folder from the extracted zip
6. Also remove the `wp-config-sample.php` and put there your `wp-config.php`
7. Via FTP, upload to server all the files

Now it should work, but probably you have to change hosting...

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like it's running ok from front end.
I did get a notice saying that your Wordpress Database needed upgrading though.
I'd suggest you visit: http://www.azraar.com/wp-admin and click that (after backing up your DB as previously suggested) as it might fix your problem.
Good luck